# Network problem?

Tags: proxy

in my company our network department people stop the accessing of google,yahoo website for the employees using router how can i access the google and yahoo now please help thank u

Comment: Trying to violate your company policy??

Comment: probably best not to ask this on the site where sysadmins hang out :)

Comment: are you able to access bing? maybe you work for microsoft? lol

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to ask questions on a sysadmin site about how to bypass systems put in place by your sysadmin. He/she won't thank us any more than we would if the situation was reversed. Besides that, this is not a sysadmin question.

Comment: In some ways, answers to this question would be somewhat useful.  It would help us see if there are any new methods people are trying to get around the firewall.

Answer (score 3):

If you (really) need to access Google or Yahoo for work purposes, you should talk to your management and get them to arrange for a way to do it.  I personally use both Google and Yahoo as part of my work ... and would find it very hard (maybe even impossible) to do certain tasks without them.

If you actually want to use Google and/or Yahoo for non-work-related purposes, either get a broadband connection at home, or change employers.  If you try to subvert the router restrictions for no good reason, you deserve to be fired.

Comment: P.S. If you want help with sending spam or hacking your bosses password, I ain't going to help you with that either!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should still be able to access those sites, provided a few things.

1. You use an external Proxy server to do all the website fetching.
2. You can access the external proxy servers via port 80 OR another port that hasn't been unblocked.

or

1. You another [anonymous proxy website](http://www.youhide.com/) to let IT get your data....

An external proxy server are generally called [anonymous proxy servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_proxy#Anonymizing_proxy_server) if you don't know them ... or you can use another companies proxy, which is accessible via the public / a public IP.

So .. scamper off to [Google](http://www.google.com.au/#hl=en&safe=off&q=anonymous+proxy+list&meta=&aq=f&oq=anonymous+proxy+list&fp=1d6be0c0580318f7) to search for them ... OH WAIT! u can't BWAHEBAHEBAWHEHAWEBAWHEA...

So maybe [Bing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=anonymous+proxy+list&form=QBLH&filt=all&qs=AS&pq=anonymous+proxy) can do it....

None-the-less, i wouldn't use anonymous services like those .. who knows what they are doing ... especially if u're using usernames/passwords!! nasty :(

But most importantly ... dude/dudette/thing ... it's blocked for a reason ... tsk tsk trying to break out.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how good the system administrator is.  You may be able to get around it using some form of VPN/proxy/tunnel, but you will not be able to do it in a way that they cannot detected if the administrator is interesting in doing so.  A quick search of google will reveal many methods.  The right one for your network depends on how your administrator has configured things.

My suggestion is to buy a smartphone with a data plan and use your own Internet access which they will not have any control over.